# js code optimization for calling stylesheets dependent on end users' time

Tags: javascript

the following code works. it's simple but i'm sure there will be a better and/or more optimal way to write it without using jquery but i don't know of any other way to do it and keep it working as it does now.

```
<script>
function getStylesheet() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='{T_THEME_PATH}/morning.css'>");
    }
    if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='{T_THEME_PATH}/day.css'>");
    }
    if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='{T_THEME_PATH}/evening.css'>");
    }
    if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24 || 0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
     document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='{T_THEME_PATH}/night.css'>");
    }
}

getStylesheet();
```

edit: i'm just needing to know if there is a better way to write the js i posted. better as in what flaws or incorrect coding i have

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Michael Hobbs sorry, i didn't think to actually have it posted as a question. i'm just needing to know if there is a better way to write the js i posted. better as in what flaws or incorrect coding i have. i will edit my post to include this info

Comment: If you're not doing performance testing then you will most likely be optimizing the wrong thing. Remember that. Spend your time learning to code better rather than wasting it optimizing to save a few milliseconds. Also, see @lawrence-witt answer.

Comment: with my current health issues i'm unable to actually learn anything new. anything that i have learned over about the last 2.5 years i'm unable to retain. i had taken some online  courses at codecademy 2 years ago but could never remember any of it. money wasted. i used to be able to figure things out for the most part by myself but not anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is mostly fine for what you're doing, although the main issue is the use of `document.write` which is generally considered to be [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) when inserting elements. If you wanted to clean things up a bit you could do something like this, which focuses on the breakpoints rather than ranges of values:

```
function getStylesheet() {
  const currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  const breaks = [5, 11, 16, 22, 24];
  const extensions = ['night', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening', 'night'];
  const match = breaks.findIndex(num => currentTime < num);

  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const sheetLink = document.createElement('link');
  sheetLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
  sheetLink.href = `T_THEME_PATH/${extensions[match]}.css`;

  head.appendChild(sheetLink);
}

getStylesheet();
```

This approach assumes that the time format will always 0-24, and requires the two arrays to be exactly related, so it's not that flexible but you might like to use it. It also uses a template literal to construct the `href` once rather than writing it out multiple times.

One final note - there was no jQuery in your code, it's all vanilla javascript.

Comment: thank you. the only thing i had to change was to put brackets around T_THEME_PATH so it would be like {T_THEME_PATH}